# Trying to create a function that will join words together from two unevenly sized vectors of strings

Tags: c++, stl

If I have these two vectors:

```
vec1: "hello", "world"
vec2: "it", "is", "sunny", "today"

resultvector: "helloit", "worldis"
```

I need to use stl for this, and a functor. So far what I have throws a stackdump error:

My functor:
reads in two std strings, and "+" them together, returns result of operation.

My function:

Creates a `std::list` list, and uses `std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), list.begin(), functor()); return list;`

My suspicion is that I don't know how to make it iterate only till the end of smaller container, and also maybe I am doing something funky with list.begin() and need something else for it.

Any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Note: the two vectors are `std::vector<string>` and result is `std::list<string>`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Thank you Leonid Volnitsky, it fixed everything

Comment: Lacks the minimal understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct ff
{
 string operator ()(const string& x, const string& y ){
 return x+y; }
};

int main ()
{
 vector <string> vec1{"hello", "world"};
 vector <string> vec2{ "it", "is", "sunny", "today"};
 vector <string> resultvector;
 std::transform(
     vec1.begin(), vec1.begin()+min(vec1.size(),vec2.size()),
     vec2.begin(), 
     back_inserter(resultvector), 
     ff() 
     ); 

for(auto i:resultvector)
    cout<<i<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `transform` call, use `back_inserter(list)` in place of `list.begin()`. `back_inserter` produces an iterator that translates assignments into `push_back` calls on underlying container.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::transform(
     vec1.begin(),
     vec1.begin()+std::min(vec1.size(),vec2.size()),
     vec2.begin(), 
     std::back_inserter(list), 
     functor()
);
```

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, using names used by STD (list), is not recommended.